# laravel vue multi language site : String as key

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have been searching for an easy no plugin solution.

I am using laravel's string as key format for my translation file. I have `fr.json` file and inside this file I have all the texts and it's translations. 
It works fine for blade but not being able to use it in my `.vue` files.

Please help me how can I use this fr.json file in all of my .vue file. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please be more specific about what isn't working as expected. And please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get your translation files in Vue, you'd have to import them in your javascript.

First. Set a meta tag in your head eith the current language:

`<meta name='locale' content='{{app()->getLocale()}}' />`

And then in your javascript for this example `resources/assets/js/app.js`:

```
var locale = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
var lang = {
    locale: require('../../lang/' + locale + '.json')
}
```

Maybe you can do the same for the default/fallback language. Then a translate function would look like this:

```
function trans(key, replace) {
    var message;
    if (lang[locale][key] != undefined) {
         message = lang[locale][key];
    } else if (lang[defaultLocale][key] != undefined) {
         message = lang[defaultLocale][key];
    }
    if (message) {
        // Loop through each item of replace and string replace the message.

        return message;
    }

    return key;
}
```

Something like this could work I think. Didn't test it and needs some tweaking but I think that this should be the idea when solving this problem.